# Perl unknown template of unpack

Tags: perl, unpack

Somebody can tell me the meaning in Perl of

```
unpack('@76b9', $buf);
```

(specially the `'@76b9'` part).
Can this function with zero as parameter return something different than zero?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "zero as parameter".  Is it `$buf = 0`, `$buf = 'zero'`, `$buf = "\0"`, ...

Answer (score 3):

```
@76
```

> `@` Null-fill or truncate to absolute position, counted from the start of the innermost ()-group

```
b9
```

> `b` A bit string (ascending bit order inside each byte, like vec()).

Example:

```
unpack('@76b9', (" "x76) . chr(4) . chr(1) )   ==>  001000001
                                                    --------|
                                                        |   |
                             \004 in ascending order-----   |
                                                            |
                             LSB of \001 --------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

`@76` means to skip to byte 76 in `$buf`.

`b9` means to unpack a 9-bit integer field.

See [perlpacktut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) for a tutorial on `pack` and `unpack`.